# Unable to write dataframe of pyspark into mysql database

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, avro

I am a new bee to spark. I am trying to write the pyspark dataframe into mysql database. I am getting a null pointer exception.

Is this any how related Avro format which is mentioned [Spark giving Null Pointer Exception while performing jdbc save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088036/spark-giving-null-pointer-exception-while-performing-jdbc-save).

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://*******:7077").appName("amazon-insights").config("spark.executor.memory", "6gb").config("spark.jars","/usr/local/spark/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar").getOrCreate()

reviews.write.jdbc(url="jdbc:mysql:://**host***:3306/sparkjobs",table="reviews",mode="append",properties={"driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","user":"****","password":"****"})
```

Error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   o545.jdbc. : java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:99)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)